# What is the Cordova file function success object type?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to figure out the type of the `success` object for any of the [cordova file API](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) functions? For instance, for the `checkFile` function it should logically be a boolean `true` / `false` reply.
Or is the `then` branch the positive - file exists branch and the `error` branch when the file does not exist?

```
$cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, "some_file.txt")
      .then(function (success) {
        // success
      }, function (error) {
        // error
      });
```

However, it's pretty hard to tell from the documentation.
Docs states:  `Returns Object` , and since it seems difficult to detect from a standard browser, it's some dark magic phone debugging to get familiar with the API. Any hints welcome.

---

After some exercises and looking at the [source code](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/blob/master/src/plugins/file.js), this is how I now got to understand the cordova file library with the `checkFile` function:

```
this.checkBackupExists = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, this.backupFileName)
        .then(function (success) {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }, function (error) {
            // error
            if(error.code==1) #NOT_FOUND_ERR
                deferred.resolve(false);
            else
                deferred.reject(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a successful run of 'checkFile' with result in the 'then' callback being called and and of the errors occurring here http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/#file-error-codes will result in the 'error' callback being called... with 'error' being that error code or an object containing the code.

Comment: $cordovaFile.checkFile('',backupFileName)
  .then(function (success) {
   deferred.resolve(true);
  }, function (error) {
   // error
   if(error.code==1)
    deferred.resolve(false);
   else
    deferred.reject(error);
  });